# Setting Visual Studio Project with SDL and GLEW

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2012

I'm new to using Visual Studio and the libraries OpenGL and SDL.

I'm having trouble setting up my program and keep running into errors when I try to build it.

Can anyone help me solve the following -

```
Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glewInit@0 referenced in function _SDL_main    
Error   2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glewGetErrorString@4 referenced in function _SDL_main  
Error   3   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp____GLEW_VERSION_3_0 
Error   4   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup   
Error   5   error LNK1120: 4 unresolved externals   
    6   IntelliSense: identifier "GLuint" is undefined  
    7   IntelliSense: identifier "GLuint" is undefined
```

This is my code -

main.c

```
#include<SDL.h>
#include<GL\glew.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char shouldExit = 0;
int main(void)
{
    /* Initialize SDL *l
    if( SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_VIDEO ) < 0 ) {
    return 1;
    }
    /* Create the window, OpenGL context */
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_BUFFER_SIZE, 32);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);
    SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow(
        "TestSDL",
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
        640, 480,
        SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
    if (!window) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not create window.ErrorCode = %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        SDL_Quit();
        return 1;
    }
    SDL_GL_CreateContext(window);
    /* Make sure we have a recent version of OpenGL */
    GLenum glewError = glewInit();
    if (glewError != GLEW_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not initialize glew.ErrorCode = %s\n", glewGetErrorString(glewError));
        SDL_Quit();
        return 1;
    }
    if (!GLEW_VERSION_3_0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "OpenGL max supported version is too low.\n");
        SDL_Quit();
        return 1;
    }
    /* Setup OpenGL state */
    glViewport(0, 0, 640, 480);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glOrtho(0, 640, 480, 0, 0, 100);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    /* The game loop */
    while (!shouldExit) {
        // Handle OS message pump
        SDL_Event event;
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
            switch (event.type) {
            case SDL_QUIT:
                shouldExit = 1;
            }
        }
        glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        /* Game logic goes here */
        SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window);
    }
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

DrawUtils.c

```
/***********************************************************************
 Utilities for loading and drawing sprites.
*/
#include<GL/glew.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<assert.h>

/* Load a file into an OpenGL texture, and return that texture. */
GLuint glTexImageTGAFile( const char* filename, int* outWidth, int* outHeight )
{
    const int BPP = 4;

    /* open the file */
    FILE* file = fopen( filename, "rb" );
    if( file == NULL ) {
        fprintf( stderr, "File: %s -- Could not open for reading.\n", filename );
        return 0;
    }

    /* skip first two bytes of data we don't need */
    fseek( file, 2, SEEK_CUR );

    /* read in the image type.  For our purposes the image type should
     * be either a 2 or a 3. */
    unsigned char imageTypeCode;
    fread( &imageTypeCode, 1, 1, file );
    if( imageTypeCode != 2 && imageTypeCode != 3 ) {
        fclose( file );
        fprintf( stderr, "File: %s -- Unsupported TGA type: %d\n", filename, imageTypeCode );
        return 0;
    }

    /* skip 9 bytes of data we don't need */
    fseek( file, 9, SEEK_CUR );

    /* read image dimensions */
    int imageWidth = 0;
    int imageHeight = 0;
    int bitCount = 0;
    fread( &imageWidth, sizeof( short ), 1, file );
    fread( &imageHeight, sizeof( short ), 1, file );
    fread( &bitCount, sizeof( unsigned char ), 1, file );
    fseek( file, 1, SEEK_CUR );

    /* allocate memory for image data and read it in */
    unsigned char* bytes = (unsigned char*)calloc( imageWidth * imageHeight * BPP, 1 );

    /* read in data */
    if( bitCount == 32 ) {
        int it;
        for( it = 0; it != imageWidth * imageHeight; ++it ) {
            bytes[ it * BPP + 0 ] = fgetc( file );
            bytes[ it * BPP + 1 ] = fgetc( file );
            bytes[ it * BPP + 2 ] = fgetc( file );
            bytes[ it * BPP + 3 ] = fgetc( file );
        }
    } else {
        int it;
        for( it = 0; it != imageWidth * imageHeight; ++it ) {
            bytes[ it * BPP + 0 ] = fgetc( file );
            bytes[ it * BPP + 1 ] = fgetc( file );
            bytes[ it * BPP + 2 ] = fgetc( file );
            bytes[ it * BPP + 3 ] = 255;
        }
    }

    fclose( file );

    /* load into OpenGL */
    GLuint tex;
    glGenTextures( 1, &tex );
    glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex );
    glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, imageWidth, imageHeight, 0,
                  GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, bytes );
    glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST );
    glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST );

    free( bytes );

    if( outWidth ) {
        *outWidth = imageWidth;
    }
    if( outHeight ) {
        *outHeight = imageHeight;
    }
    return tex;
}

/* Draw the sprite */
void glDrawSprite( GLuint tex, int x, int y, int w, int h )
{
    glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex );
    glBegin( GL_QUADS );
    {
    glColor3ub( 255, 255, 255 );
    glTexCoord2f( 0, 1 );
    glVertex2i( x, y );
    glTexCoord2f( 1, 1 );
    glVertex2i( x + w, y );
    glTexCoord2f( 1, 0 );
    glVertex2i( x + w, y + h );
    glTexCoord2f( 0, 0 );
    glVertex2i( x, y + h );
    }
    glEnd();
}
```

DrawUtils.h

```
#ifndef DRAWUTILS_H
#define DRAWUTILS_H

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

GLuint glTexImageTGAFile( const char* filename, int* outWidth, int* outHeight );
void glDrawSprite( GLuint tex, int x, int y, int w, int h );

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif
```

Am I missing an #include?

Comment: Not the answer to your problem, but worth pointing out: The comment above `SDL_Init()` is unterminated because you have an `l` instead of a `/` at the end (`/* Initialize SDL *l`) so SDL will not be initialised.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you're missing a library. You're including the GLEW header file(s):

```
#include<GL\glew.h>
```

However, header files only define the function *prototypes* (such as `glewInit()`) - the actual *implementations* of those functions will be stored in a `.lib` (or `.a`) file, which you must link with in order to build your project.

It's been a while since I used Visual Studio, but I'd think that you would normally set up linker options as part of your project configuration. However, it *is* possible to specify linker options within your code, if you must:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "glew/glew32s.lib")
```

Note that the `#pragma` method is MSVC-specific and probably won't work on other compilers.

If you can't be bothered fiddling around with linker options, you could always just [add `glew.c` to your project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11027485/linking-to-glew-in-c) instead.

---

One other thing: You're using `GLuint` in `DrawUtils.h` without including either `gl.h` or `glew.h`:

```
GLuint glTexImageTGAFile( const char* filename, int* outWidth, int* outHeight );
void glDrawSprite( GLuint tex, int x, int y, int w, int h );
```

Answer (score -1):

Regarding Visual Studio 2017, OpenGL, SDL2 and GLEW, I recommend [this](https://www.wikihow.com/Create-an-OpenGL-SDL-GLEW-Project-with-a-Template-in-Visual-Studio-2017) webpage.
I copy and paste text only.

**Part A - Downloading SDL and GLEW**

**A1** Create a folder OpenGL. In directory (disk) C:, create (by right click > New > Folder) a new folder with name *OpenGL*.

**A2** Download the *SDL2-devel-2.0.8-VC.zip (Visual C++ 32/64-bit)*. It can be found at https://www.libsdl.org/download-2.0.php. Scroll to the bottom of the page and find Development Libraries.

**A2a** Download the version for Visual C++. It is the *SDL2-devel-2.0.8-VC.zip (Visual C++ 32/64-bit)*. Navigate (always by double click) to C: > OpenGL.

**A2b** Drag (or, by right click, copy and paste) folder *SDL2-2.0.8* from the window where it is downloaded, into folder *OpenGL*.

**A2c** If the folder *SDL2-devel-2.0.8-VC* is downloaded, double click it to get *SDL2-2.0.8*.

**A3** Download the GLEW. At http://glew.sourceforge.net/ below Downloads click *Windows 32-bit and 64-bit*. Navigate to C: > OpenGL. Drag (or, by right click, copy and paste) folder *glew-2.1.0* from the window where it is downloaded, into folder *OpenGL.

**A3a** If folder *glew-2.1.0-win32* is downloaded, double click it for get *glew-2.1.0*.

**Part B - Creating a Visual Studio Project**

**B1** Create an empty project.

**B1a** At the Visual Studio main menu, click *File*. Then go to New > Project…

**B1b** In the left part of the *New Project* window, click *Visual C++* if it is not clicked.

**B1c** In the center of the screen click *Empty Project*.

**B1d** Below that, find the Name text box, type *Project-0*.

**B1e** Next to Location text box, click *Browse...* and navigate to C: > OpenGL.

**B1f** Click *Select a folder*. The Location in *New Project* window is C:\OpenGL.

**B1g** Make sure the *Create directory for solution* box is not checked.

**B1h** Click OK.

**B2** Add your source file to the Project.

**B2a** In the *Solution Explorer* window (at the left side of the screen), right click the *Source Files* folder (the last one).

**B2b** Click Add > New Item…

**B2c** In the *Add New Item - Project-0* window, click *C++ File (.cpp)* (the first one) from the middle of the window. In Name text box type *Main.cpp*.

**B2d.** The Location is C:\OpenGL\Project-0.

**B2e** Click the Add button. The file will open in the main text editor but leave the file blank for now.

**Part C - Installing SDL and GLEW on a Project**

**C1** Add the *Include* folders.

**C1a** Configure the *Additional Include Directories*: In *Solution Explorer* right click on the name of your project, that is *Project-0*, and select *Properties*.

**C1b** Add SDL's *include* folder: Open the C/C++ drop-down menu. Click General > Additional Include Directories > down arrow at the right of the field > Edit in the drop down menu.

**C1c** In *Additional Include Directories*, click the first icon > copy and paste, *C:\OpenGL\SDL2-2.0.8\include*

**C1d** Add GLEW's *include* folder: Click again the first icon > copy and paste: *C:\OpenGL\glew-2.1.0\include* Click OK on *Additional Include Directories* window.

**C2** Add the *x86* and *Win32* folders.

**C2a** Configure the linker *Additional Library Directories*: Open the Linker drop-down menu, and click *General*.

**C2b** Add the *x86* folder: Click *Additional Library Directories* entry, and click the down arrow at the right of the field. Click *Edit* in the drop-down menu.

**C2c** In *Additional Library Directories* click the first icon > copy and paste, *C:\OpenGL\SDL2-2.0.8\lib\x86*

**C2d** Add the *Win32* folder: Click the first icon > copy and paste, *C:\OpenGL\glew-2.1.0\lib\Release\Win32* Click OK.

**C3** Add the four *library* files.

**C3a** Configure the linker *Additional Dependencies*: In the *Linker* drop-down menu, click *Input*. Click the Additional Dependencies entry > the down arrow at the right of the field > Edit in the drop-down menu.

**C3b** On the top-most text box of the *Additional Dependencies* window, copy and paste, *SDL2.lib; SDL2main.lib; glew32.lib; opengl32.lib* Click OK in the *Additional Dependencies* window.

**C4** Configure the linker *subsystem to console*.

**C4a** In the Linker drop-down menu, click System > SubSystem. Click the down arrw and select *Console(/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE)* from the dropdown menu. Click *Apply*, then OK on the *Project Property Pages* window.

**C5** Copy *SDL2.dll* file from *x86* folder, and paste to *Project-0* folder.

**C5a** Navigate to C: > OpenGL > SDL2-2.0.8 > lib > x86. Inside *x86* folder click SDL2.dll file > right-click > Copy.

**C5b** Navigate to C: > OpenGL > Project-0. Right-click an empty area in Project-0 folder, and select *Paste*.

**C5c** The *SDL2.dll* file should now be in your project directory along with your *Main.cpp* file and a few other files created by Visual Studio.

**C6** Copy the *glew32.dll* file from *Win32* and paste to Project folder.

**C6a** Navigate to C: > OpenGL > glew-2.1.0 > bin > Release > Win32. Click glew32.dll > right-click > Copy.

**C6b** Navigate to C: > OpenGL > Project-0. Right-click an empty area in *Project-0* folder, and select *Paste*.

**C6c** The *glew32.dll* file should now be in *Project-0* folder along with *Main.cpp, SDL2.dll*, and a few other files created by Visual Studio.

**Part D - Testing and Debugging Your Project**

**D1** Download the code: Click http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/51_SDL_and_modern_opengl/index.php > Scroll down and find *Download the media and source code for this tutorial here*. Click *here* and download *51_SDL_and_modern_opengl.cpp* folder. Double click it > double click file of same name. Its code will appear in Visual Studio by the side of *Main.cpp* file. Copy the code (413 lines) and paste on *Main.cpp* code area. On V.S. main menu click the green arrow *Local Windows Debugger* and wait... If everything went well two windows appear: one black and one with title: *SDL Tutorial* and inside a white square with black background. If there is any problem try fix the error(s). If you fail, repeat above steps.

**Part E - Creating a Project with OpenGL-SDL-GLEW Template in Visual Studio 2017**

**E1** Create a project template: Go to Visual Studio main menu and, while *Project-0* is open, click Project > Export Template.... On *Export template* Wizard check *Project Template*, if it's not checked. Click *Next >*. On *Select Template Options*, in *Template name* text box type: *OpenGL-SDL-GLEW*. Click *Finish*. Template has been created.

**E2** Create OpenGL-SDL-GLEW project with created Template

**E2a** On V.S. main menu click File > New > Project.... On the *New Project* window, click template: *OpenGL-SDL-GLEW*. In Name text field, type: *Project-1*. Be sure *Create directory for solution* is unchecked. Click OK.

**E2b** On *Solution Explorer*, double click *Source Files*. Click Main.cpp > right click > click Exclude From Project.

**E2c** Right click Source Files > Add > New Item.... On *Add New Item - Project-1* window, click *C++ File (.cpp)*. In *Name:* text box type: *Main.cpp*. The *Location* should be C:\OpenGL\Project-1. Click Add. Now on *Solution Explore*, below *Source Files*, you have the new *Main.cpp* file.

**E3** Add *SDL2.dll* file to project-folder

**E3a** Navigate to C: > OpenGL > Project-0 > click file SDL2.dll > right click > click Copy.

**E3b** Navigate to C: > OpenGL > Project-1 > click on empty area > right click > click Paste.

**E3c** Now file *SDL2.dll* is in folder *Project-1* among *Main.cpp* and other 4 files.

**E4** Add *glew32.dll* file to project-folder

**E4a** Navigate to C: > OpenGL > Project-0 > click file glew32.dll > right click > click Copy.

**E4b** Navigate to C: > OpenGL > Project-1 > click on empty area > right click > click Paste.

**E4c** Now file *glew32.dll* is in folder *Project-1* among *SDL2.dll*, *Main.cpp* and other 4 files.

**E5** Test your project as above. Good job.

**Tip**

**Remember the 3 extra steps you have to take:** Creating project with OpenGL-SDL-GLEW Template in Visual Studio 2017 is like creating an ordinary C++ project, but with three more steps:

**1** In *Solution Explorer*, *Source Files*, the source file (*Main.cpp* in the example above) of the template project (*Project-0*, in the example) should be excluded from new project (*Project-1* in example).

**2** The file *SDL2.dll* should be copied from a previous project and pasted into new project.

**3** The file *glew32.dll* should be copied from a previous project and pasted into new project.